# Android: acsess to i2c device from java app

Tags: java, android, i2c

I have rooted Samsung Galaxy S10+ android phone and I want to write a quick testing app in java to check if a chip I am going to solder (I know where the chip should be and I know what chip it is) on my phone is working properly (if a chip is uvailable on adress 0x20D for instance, then it was soldered properly, otherwise not)

But I have no idea where to start

I read somewhere that you need to write a driver for a device, before you can even see if its working

So is there a better way? (I will write a driver, once I know that device is working properly)

Like a simple library that I can put an i2c adress into and it would return true if device is there, false otherwise?

There is also a second problem
If I want to test the app I would need to see if the app itself is working on a built in i2c device (**i2cdetect -y 1** told me that there is something on 0x50)

but all the built in devices already have drivers written so they are holding the address hostge, which means, I cannot get acsess to any build in i2c device just using java even if rooted?

So hopefully someone knows what to do

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards